# ‘call at’ vs ‘stop at’ vs ‘serve’

Tags: word-choice

I work part-time for a local public transport company translating diversion notices and other announcements to English to help foreigners in general and tourists stay up to date with the changes, road works etc.

I often struggle when choosing a particular expression to use: in general I prefer the UK English in my everyday communication and *also* this is what I tend to use when doing this work, but I do acknowledge some terms used in the UK are UK-specific and are not widely recognised or known outside of it.

One of such terms is *call at*. I’ve not used it yet for describing route changes, because I (as a non-native English speaker) remember myself being a bit confused about it when I heard it for the first time, so I usually write:

> services to X are diverted via Y and Z stopping at Stop 1, Stop 2 and a temporary stop Temporary Stop

Sometimes I use the verb *serve*:

> diverted via X serving all stops along the diversion route

> the following stops are only served by services to X: …

Sometimes I use both:

> Services to X don’t serve Y, stopping at the Z stop

However, when I check announcements e.g. TfL publishes, they often use terms such as *calling at X, Y, Z*, *missing P, Q, R* (I use *skipping* for this one).
Should I continue avoiding *calling at* (and maybe *missing*) or are my fears of the readers not understanding this unsubstantiated?

Comment: This AmE speaker would be initially puzzled by "calling at" and find "stopping at" with "temporary stop at" to be clearer. I've heard of a "gentleman caller" but am puzzled by the notion of a train visiting a station: is it discharging passengers there or just tipping its hat and sitting on the porch?

Comment: _Call at_ is idiomatic in this sense in British English.

Comment: Assuming we are not talking about a boat, in AmE, *calling at* loosely implies the driver might exit the vehicle and enter the establishment or knock on the door. In other words: an extra service above a normal route stop.